# The application leaves at the location where the secondary thread handler is created

Tags: android, multithreading

Wrote an application to an Android to understand the control of view items from the child thread. Took the main looper from named Mainactivity and passed it through the constructor to a class that implements a child thread and that just changes the contents of TextView through callback.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView textView = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.i("create", Thread.currentThread().toString());
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    HandlerTextView handlerTextView = new HandlerTextView(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
    handlerTextView.registerMessage(new Message() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(String msg) {
            textView.setText(msg);
        }
    });
    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("two", HandlerThread.NORM_PRIORITY);
    if(handlerThread != null){
        Handler a = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
        if(a != null) {
            a.post(handlerTextView);
        }
    }
  }
}

public class HandlerTextView implements Runnable {

private Looper mainLooper = null;
private TextView textView = null;
private Socket socket = null;
private Message message = null;

public HandlerTextView(Looper looper) {
    this.mainLooper = looper;
}

public void registerMessage(Message m) {
    this.message = m;
}

private void setText(final String str) {
    Handler handler = new Handler(mainLooper);
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            message.handleMessage(str);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void run() {
    setText("dfsdfsdfsdf");
  }
}
```

> Created a new Handlerthread thread handler object, took it looper
>   and passed it to the constructor of the new handler handler and it
>   The error: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{elaneturn.com.myapplication/elaneturn.com.myapplication.MainActiv                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Call handlerThread.start() before creating Handler:

```
handlerThread.start();
Handler a = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
```